# How to count specific no of items in Postman response

Tags: count, postman

I am new to postman. I have response and I want to count how many items with equipment_id =53
Here is my code which I tried but I couldn't see any output in console.

## Response

```
[
    {
        "id": 373,
        "user_id": 119118855,
        "location_id": 9999,
        "duration": 0,
        "watts": 0,
        "timestamp": "2019-07-12T00:00:00.000Z",
        "equipment_id": 53,
        "name": "10 Ride",
        "equipment_name": "Bike2"
    },
    {
        "id": 376,
        "user_id": 119118855,
        "location_id": 9999,
        "duration": 0,
        "watts": 0,
        "timestamp": "2019-06-13T00:00:00.000Z",
        "equipment_id": 53,
        "name": "10 min Ride",
        "equipment_name": "Bike2"
    },
    {
        "id": 338,
        "user_id": 119118855,
        "location_id": 9999,
        "duration": 0,
        "watts": 0,
        "timestamp": "2019-07-12T00:00:00.000Z",
        "equipment_id": 17,
        "name": "20 min Ride",
        "equipment_name": "Bike"
    },
]
```

## Postman script I tried:

```
pm.test("count of records with equipment id 53",function(){
const jsonData = pm.response.json();
var count = jsonData.length;
//console.log(count);

function noofrecords (){
    _each(count.equipment_id).to.include(53);
    count++;
    console.log("Count:" + noofrecords);
```

May I know how to write script to get count of equipment_id =53
Answer should be 2 here, but I am not getting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
count = jsonData.filter( a => a["equipment_id"] === 53 ).length
```

this gives the count, here we are using array.filter to get all objects with equipment_id 53

Comment: please accept the answer by pressing the tick sign

Comment: Hi, same above response I want to count how many items with today's timestamp. I used below script to test but I am not getting correct value.~~~var count2 = jsonData.length
pm.test("There are "+ count2 +" workouts for this user during today",function () {
for (var i=0;i<jsonData.length;i++){
 if(jsonData[i].equipment_id === 53){
    count2 = jsonData.filter( b => b["timestamp"] === now).length
} }
console.log("Today's workout Count:"+ count2);

});